# Does the raspberry pi with android support usb devices?

Tags: usb, android, input-device

I have a proprietary USB-C device (A Philips transducer) which I need to get real time data from to my pc for real time analysis. Only problem is that the device is only supported by an android app (Philips Lumify).

I tried using different android emulators with the APK installed, but as far as I know, android emulators currently don't support USB passthrough. Another option would be to use something similar to VNC on the android device to stream the screen capture over a network, but there would be some latency which is not desirable.

The option i'm currently considering is installing android on a SBC, in this case an rpi. And capturing the video output of the app running using an HDMI capture card.

So my question is, if a raspberry pi 3/4 with android recognizes usb devices.

Better solutions than my hacky idea are also welcome.

Edit: 
A simple solution is to use virtualbox with android-x86 with usb passthrough enabled